# How do I retrieve the second primary key from table three in this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can retrieve the primary key value from a newly inserted row with `SET @sqlindent= SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. I have a stored procedure that has three insert statements into three tables.

- Step one: insert into table one new row, retrieve Primary key value `(SET @sqlindent= SCOPE_IDENTITY())`
- Step two: insert into table two fields from table one. `Insert Into table two [id] Value (@sqlindent)` So table two id field = table one primary key.
- Step three: insert into table three from table two. `Insert Into table three [id] Value (@sqlindent)` So table three id filed also = table one and two primary key

Lastly I need to retrieve the primary key value from table three and UPDATE table two with the primary key from table three. This is where I need assistance. How do I retrieve the second primary key from table three?

Here's what I have so far. All statements work except the last

```
SET @sqlidentsrvat = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Thanks as usual.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xxxxxxxxxx]
    @AccountCompany varchar(100),
    @AccountAddress1 varchar(256),
    @AccountAddress2 varchar(256),
    @AccountCity varchar(100),
    @AccountState varchar(4),
    @AccountZip nchar(10),
    @AccountCountry varchar(80),
    @AccountPriPhone varchar(22),
    @AccountSecPhone varchar(22),
    @AccountCreateDate DateTime,
    @sqlident int output,
    @AccountContactISPrimary int,
    @AccountContactNameFirst varchar(35),
    @AccountContactNameLast varchar(35),
    @AccountContactPhone1 varchar(22),
    @AccountContactPhone1Ext varchar(8),
    @AccountContactPhone2 varchar(22),
    @AccountContactPhone2Ext varchar(8),
    @AccountContactEmail varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlidentsrvat INT;

    INSERT INTO [Account_tbl] ([AccountCompany], [AccountAddress1],[AccountAddress2], [AccountCity], [AccountState], [AccountZip], [AccountCountry],[AccountPriPhone], [AccountSecPhone])
    VALUES (@AccountCompany, @AccountAddress1, @AccountAddress2, @AccountCity, @AccountState, @AccountZip, @AccountCountry, @AccountPriPhone, @AccountSecPhone)

    SET @sqlident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO [AccountContacts_tbl] ([AccountNumberID],[AccountContactISPrimary], [AccountContactNameFirst], [AccountContactNameLast],[AccountContactPhone1], [AccountContactPhone2], [AccountContactEmail],[AccountContactPhone1Ext], [AccountContactPhone2Ext])
    VALUES (@sqlident, @AccountContactISPrimary, @AccountContactNameFirst, @AccountContactNameLast, @AccountContactPhone1, @AccountContactPhone2, @AccountContactEmail, @AccountContactPhone1Ext, @AccountContactPhone2Ext)

    INSERT INTO [ServiceAtLoc_tbl] ([ServiceAccountID],[ServiceAtCompanyName], [ServiceAtAddress1], [ServiceAtAddress2],[ServiceAtCity], [ServiceAtState], [ServiceAtZip], [ServiceAtCountry])
    VALUES(@sqlident, @AccountCompany, @AccountAddress1, @AccountAddress2, @AccountCity, @AccountState, @AccountZip, @AccountCountry)

    SET @sqlidentsrvat = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE AccountContacts_tbl
    SET AccountSvcAtID = @sqlidentsrvat
    FROM AccountContacts_tbl
    INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceAtLoc_tbl ON dbo.AccountContacts_tbl.AccountSvcAtID = dbo.ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID
    WHERE AccountContacts_tbl.AccountSvcAtID = ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID
END
```

For those reading here's the final code that does as I needed. Thanks for the help all who responded.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXXXXXXXXX]

    @AccountCompany varchar(100),
    @AccountAddress1 varchar(256),
    @AccountAddress2 varchar(256),
    @AccountCity varchar(100),
    @AccountState varchar(4),
    @AccountZip nchar(10),
    @AccountCountry varchar(80),
    @AccountPriPhone varchar(22),
    @AccountSecPhone varchar(22),
    @AccountCreateDate DateTime,
    @sqlident int output,

    @AccountContactISPrimary int,
    @AccountContactNameFirst varchar(35),
    @AccountContactNameLast varchar(35),
    @AccountContactPhone1 varchar(22),
    @AccountContactPhone1Ext varchar(8),
    @AccountContactPhone2 varchar(22),
    @AccountContactPhone2Ext varchar(8),
    @AccountContactEmail varchar(100),
    @ServiceIdent int output

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO [Account_tbl] 
    ([AccountCompany],[AccountAddress1],[AccountAddress2],[AccountCity], [AccountState],[AccountZip],[AccountCountry],[AccountPriPhone],[AccountSecPhone])
    Values
    (@AccountCompany,@AccountAddress1,@AccountAddress2,@AccountCity,@AccountState,@AccountZip,@AccountCountry,@AccountPriPhone,@AccountSecPhone)

SET @sqlident = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [AccountContacts_tbl]
    ([AccountNumberID],[AccountContactISPrimary],[AccountContactNameFirst],[AccountContactNameLast],[AccountContactPhone1],[AccountContactPhone2],[AccountContactEmail],[AccountContactPhone1Ext],[AccountContactPhone2Ext])
    Values
    (@sqlident,@AccountContactISPrimary,@AccountContactNameFirst,@AccountContactNameLast,@AccountContactPhone1,@AccountContactPhone2,@AccountContactEmail,@AccountContactPhone1Ext,@AccountContactPhone2Ext)

INSERT INTO [ServiceAtLoc_tbl]
    ([ServiceAccountID],[ServiceAtCompanyName],[ServiceAtAddress1],[ServiceAtAddress2],[ServiceAtCity], [ServiceAtState],[ServiceAtZip],[ServiceAtCountry])
VALUES
    (@sqlident,@AccountCompany,@AccountAddress1,@AccountAddress2,@AccountCity,@AccountState,@AccountZip,@AccountCountry)

SET @ServiceIdent = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE AccountContacts_tbl
SET AccountSvcAtID = ServiceAtLocID
FROM ServiceAtLoc_tbl
WHERE ServiceAccountID = AccountNumberID and ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID = @ServiceIdent

END
```

Comment: Do all three tables have identity columns? Are all these columns also configured as primary keys, or at least with unique constraints?

Comment: If they are incrementing values, you could select the second highest value perhaps?

Comment: try output.inserted

Comment: I think you may be missing an extra where predicate on your last update here. As posted this would update the entire table which I don't think is what you want to do. Probably as simple as "AND ServiceAtLoc_tbl.[WhateverTheIdentityColumnIs] = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

Comment: Phillip, Yes all the tables had unique pri. key incrementing Columns. All three are different unique id's  SCOPE_IDENTITY() value is inserted into a second field the next table (table1id = table2,id) to keep the tables relational. Problem with your suggestion  is more then one user can be running this SP at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: Sean added:
WHERE AccountContacts_tbl.AccountSvcAtID = ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID And ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID = @sqlident

Comment: Sean I added:
WHERE AccountContacts_tbl.AccountSvcAtID = ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID And ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID = @sqlident Problem is this sp is not retreiveing the second Scope_Idendity of the second table in updating the third table. The SP executes with no error. Running the SP in SSMS shows the output value of sqlident  but no output for sqlidentsrvat  Thanks also.

Comment: Will this code DOES capture the second SCOPE_Identity
SET (AtSign)ServiceIdent = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE AccountContacts_tbl
SET AccountSvcAtID = ServiceAtLocID
FROM ServiceAtLoc_tbl
WHERE ServiceAtLocID = (atsign)ServiceIdent

But it also udpates avery row in the accountscontact_tbl not the specific row. Sadly there are no fields to compare between the tables except the identity field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the third insert, do this to update the second table...

```
-- Retrieve the primary key (from the third insert)
SET @sqlidentsrvat = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Update the record
UPDATE [AccountContacts_tbl]
SET AccountSvcAtID = @sqlidentsrvat
WHERE [AccountNumberID] = @sqlident
```

Comment: Batstos: For some reason SO will not let me answer with my changed code I did as you suggested still no luck retrieving the second SCOP_Idenyity

Comment: SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() from [ServiceAtLoc_tbl]
SET (AtSign)ServiceIdent = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

UPDATE AccountContacts_tbl
SET AccountSvcAtID = ServiceAtLocID
FROM ServiceAtLoc_tbl
inner join  dbo.AccountContacts_tbl ON dbo.AccountContacts_tbl.AccountSvcAtID = dbo.ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID
WHERE ServiceAtLoc_tbl.ServiceAtLocID = (Atsign)ServiceIdent